# Implementing finite-state machine: run-time error, why?

Tags: c++, state-machine, finite-automata

I know there are implementations of FSA available, but I'd love to know where is my mistake for learning purposes. The run-time error is usually when reading from input file with `>>`.

> The error is 'exception thrown: exercise.exe has triggered a
>   breakpoint'.

I've asked my classmates, but they were also unable to pin down the mistake.

Input:

- 1st line: number of states
- 2nd line: # of start state
- 3rd line: number of accept states
- next several lines: #s of accept states
- next line: number of transition functions
- next several lines: transition functions, in form *from to value*, where *from* and *to* are corresponding states, and *value* is a symbol
- next line: number of strings that we need to check for acceptance
- next several lines: the strings themselves

My code is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

ifstream I("input.txt");
ofstream O("output.txt");

struct arrow {
    int destination=-1;
    char c='x';
    arrow() {}
    arrow(char val, int to) {
        destination = to;
        c = val;
    }
};
struct node {
    int name=-1;
    bool accept=false;
    int ars=0;
    arrow* arrows=new arrow;
    node() {}
    node(bool isAccept, int whatName) {
        accept = isAccept;
        name = whatName;
    }
};
class fsa {
    int start;
    node* states=new node;
public:
    fsa(int n, int entrSt, int acceptSts) {
        this->start=entrSt;
        int* tempForAcceptStates = new int[acceptSts];
        for (int i = 0; i < acceptSts; i++) I >> tempForAcceptStates[i];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) { 
            int wasNodeCreated = -1;
            for (int j = 0; j < acceptSts; j++) {
                if (tempForAcceptStates[j] == i) wasNodeCreated = i;
            }
            if (wasNodeCreated >= 0) states[i] = node(true, wasNodeCreated);
            else { states[i] = node(false, i); }
        }
        int transitions;
        I >> transitions;
        for (int i = 0; i < transitions; i++) {
            int from, to;
            char val;
            I >> from >> to >> val;
            int temp = states[from].ars;
            this->states[from].arrows[temp] = arrow(val, to);
            states[from].ars++;
        }
    }
     bool isRecognized() {
         string str;
         getline(I, str);
         bool wasSymbolFound=false;
         int currentNode = this->start;
         for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
             int howManyArsCurrentNodeHas = states[currentNode].ars;
             for (int j = 0; j < howManyArsCurrentNodeHas; j++) {
                wasSymbolFound = false;
                 if (states[currentNode].arrows[j].c == str[i]) {
                     currentNode = states[currentNode].arrows[j].destination;
                     wasSymbolFound = true;
                }
                 if (wasSymbolFound==true) break;
             }
             if (wasSymbolFound == false) return false;
         }
         if (states[currentNode].accept==true) return true; else return false;
     }
};

void main() {
    int n, entrSt, acceptSts;
    I >> n >> entrSt >> acceptSts;
    fsa A(n, entrSt, acceptSts);
    int words;
    I >> words;
    for (int i = 0; i < words; i++) {
        if (A.isRecognized()) O << "YES\n"; else O << "NO\n";
    }
    }
```

Example input:

```
3
0
1
0
6
0 1 a
1 0 b
0 2 b
1 2 a
2 2 a
2 2 b
3
ab
aaa
abababab
```

Corresponding desired output:

```
YES
NO 
YES
```

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: @RomeoValentin  The error is 'exception thrown: exercise.exe has triggered a breakpoint'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep in mind that your file might not be found, or some formatting errors in the file might lead to read errors.

Unfortunately, you do no **error checking**, putting you as risk of UB, such as for example having random values in variables you thought properly read from the file. For example, on my system, trying your code without an `input.txt` file causes memory allocation exceptions to happen because `acceptSts` is a huge random number.

Now looking more in detail at what is hapening,  even with a correct consistent input file as your example, your code is doomed to fail.

In in the `fsa` constructor you initialize the `states` member with `new node`, so a pointer to a single node.  Later you assign or read from an indexed value, e.g. `states[i]`, `states[from]`, `states[temp]`.  But at no moment did you allocate an array of nodes.  So for every non zero index, you get UB, which could lead to memory corruption, abrupt program abortion, any other weird behavior, or no symptom at all.

You can correct this for example, by initializing the states in the constructor, since the finite states are known:

```
    states = new node[n];
```

Unfortunately, you have the same problem with `arrow`:

```
 states[from].arrows[temp] = arrow(val, to);
```

Not only was `arrows` in a `node` initailized with a pointer to a single arrow, causing the same issues as previously explained.  THis is more complex to address with raw allocation.  So my advice, go away from allocating arrays with `new` and try to use `vector` if you're allowed to.  vectors can dynamically grow and are less error prone.

**Not related**:

- using a global `I` and `O` and using it in class methods creates a hidden coupling, that makes the program difficult to debug.  A better approach would be to define these `fstream` objects as local objects (e.g. of `main()`), and pass them as  `istream` and `ostream` reference to the functions that need them.
- if you allocate some pointers in a constructor, you should also delete it in a destructor, or you might leak memory.  if you allocated with `new[]`, then `delete[]`.

Comment: Thank you very, very much. I added ```states = new node[n];```, and put arrows into a vector. Then the code passed all tests. Thank you for keeping me in college.

Answer (score 2):

Please add the error message, it is a pain to help you, if we don't know whats wrong.

But I think, your problem lies in the definition of `fsa::states`. You define it as `new node;`, which is a pointer to a `node` on the heap, but you want to create an array of `n` `node`s on the heap. Writing `n[i]` later tries to access some memory you have not allocated and hence you get an access violation.

Don't use C-style dynamic arrays (`new []`) in C++, use `std::vector` instead.

Comment: The error is 'exception thrown: exercise.exe has triggered a breakpoint'. (Also thanks! I've never heard about ```std::vector```, I'm looking it up.)